# How to show total attempts at the end?

Tags: python

I can't seem to be able to get the correct total number of attempts to be displayed.

```
def checkAge():
    Age=int(input("EnterAge:"))
    attempts=0

    if Age>=100:
        attempts=attempts+1;
        return checkAge()

    elif Age<=1:
        attempts=attempts+1;
        return checkAge()


    else:
        attempts=attempts+1;
        print("Your age is",Age,".")
        print("Number of attempts: ",attempts,"")
```

Typing in 234 then 432 then 52, I expect the result for the attempts to be:

```
 "Number of attempts:3"
```

but it shows me:

```
 "Number of attempts:1"
```

Comment: I'd suggest a for loop instead of recursion. `for i in itertools.count(): ...`

Comment: Since attempts is local variable, the last recursive call goes into attempts=attempts+1, so just increment it from 0 and print as 1. Either you have to use, global attempts, defined outside the method or collect and recursively sum the return values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises mainly because you try to call your function recursively when it fails, which is a bad idea, because:

- there is a limit to the number of recursive calls you can make (by default, 1000 with the common implementation of Python)
- as you would have to do here, you have to pass variables between calls of the function.
- the order of execution can become complicated to follow because of the imbricated calls / returns

The right way to do what you want here it is to use a loop:

```
 def checkAge():
    attempts = 0

    while True:
        attempts += 1
        try:
            age = int(input("Enter Age: "))
        except ValueError:
            # what we entered couldn't be converted to an integer
            continue

        if 1 < age <100:
            return age, attempts


age, attempts = checkAge()
print("Your age is {}.".format(age)) 
print("Number of attempts: ", attempts, "")
```

Sample run:

```
# Enter Age: abc
# Enter Age: 122
# Enter Age: 0
# Enter Age: 33
# Your age is 33.
# Number of attempts:  4
```

I added a `try/except` block around the call to `int(input(...))`, as this would raise an exception and crash your program otherwise if the user didn't enter a valid number.

Also, it is better for functions to return data rather than print it directly, that makes them more versatile - you can decide what you do with the returned data.

Using `format` gives you more control on the printed output (here, it allows you to have the final dot just after the number, instead of separated by an extra space).

Answer (score 2):

`attempts` is being reset to 0 on each function call. You should create a parameter that you pass to `checkAge` and remove the variable instantiation `attempts=0`.

An updated function might look like

```
def checkAge(attempts):
    Age=int(input("EnterAge:"))

    if Age>=100:
        attempts=attempts+1;
        return checkAge(attempts)

    elif Age<=1:
        attempts=attempts+1;
        return checkAge(attempts)


    else:
        attempts=attempts+1;
        print("Your age is",Age,".")
        print("Number of attempts: ",attempts,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run your method checkAge() attempts is assigned the value of 0 so no matter how often you run it, it will always do: `attempts = 0` then `attempts = 0 + 1`

You need to initialize your variable outside of your method, check if it already exists (only assign 0 if attempts is null) or implement it in a different way so it won't reset to 0 every time.